# Change Color from Launchpad-Tile

Tags: javascript, sapui5

i'm a Abap-Developer and lucky as i'am i have to program a SAPUI5/Fiori App for a Customer - great!
I watched a lot of tutorials and do my best, but when it comes to the details i have my Problems. 
So that is my Problem:

I have my Launchpad Tile with the Number of Stocked Items and if the number is lower 20, the colorcode should be changed in FF0000.

- Should i implement the logic in my launchpad.view.xml or in the Launchpad.Controller.js?
- Here is a Code Snipped from my View:

  ```
          <GenericTile header="Standrohrbestand" subheader="" frameType="OneByOne" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin" press="action"
              action:wiring="\{'press':\{'navigation':\{'routeName':'equi'\}\}\}">
              <tileContent>
                  <TileContent footer="Standrohre" unit="">
                      <content>
                          <NumericContent id="equicount" value="" icon="sap-icon://add-equipment" withMargin="false"/>
                      </content>
                  </TileContent>
              </tileContent>
          </GenericTile>
  ```

Comment: Are you using model binding for the value or do you set the value in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can use expression binding to do this. 
or you can use formatter to format the value.